# What's wrong with this math calculation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$3000 = ( p6300 + (1-p)2200 ) / 1.06
\\
3000 = p6300 + 2200 - p2200 / 1.06
\\
3000 = p4100 + 2200 / 1.06
\\
800 = p4100 / 1.06
\\
p4100 = 800\times1.06
\\
p4100 = 848
\\
p = 0.2068$$

The correct answer is $p=0.239.$
What mistake(s) have I made?

Comment: p = probability

Comment: Henry, yes. I want to solve for p

Comment: $3000 = 6300 p+\frac{2200}{1.06} (1-p)$ gives $3000\times 1.06 = 6300p \times 1.06  +2200 - 2200p$ and so $p=\frac{980}{4478}$

Comment: @OliverHouse What seems to be missing is brackets - leading to errors

Comment: Henry, the correct p that should solve the equation is 0.239. Any solutions?

Comment: In that case there should be brackets: 3000 = (p6,300 + (1-p)2,200) / 1.06 leading to the answer p=980/4100=0.239.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jaap, I didn't actually pay attention to the brackets. I'm not good at solving an equation with brackets. Could you say how you solved it with steps?

Comment: Hi rayng, thanks a lot for your efforts. I don't have advanced skills in math and, therefore, it's not clear to me. Could you show it in a simple way with the equation and values from my initial post?

Comment: I've updated my answer. if you wish to alert me of your comment, write `@ryan` anywhere in the message

Answer (score 3):

As written, the first line says that $(1 - p) 2200$ has to be divided by $1.06$. However, you're messing that up in several ways in the subsequent steps.

Edit: in the comments the OP said the correct answer is 0.239. And, also mentioned in the comments, that indicates that the original question should be
$3000 = (p 6300 + (1 - p) 2200) / 1.06.$

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I forgot the brackets

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not good at solving an equation with brackets. Could you show it in a simple way, with steps, with the equation and values from my initial post?

Click [here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/3000%20%3D%20%5Cleft(p6300%20%2B%20%5Cleft(1-p%5Cright)2200%5Cright)%20%2F%201.06?or=input) for the step-by-step working with the correct algebraic manipulations.

Regarding your suggested working, note that when you have parentheses in an arithmetic expression, first perform the operations within the innermost pair then keep working outwards. Also, note that:

1. \begin{align}(a+b)c/d&=\frac{ac+bc}d\\\\&\ne ac+\frac{bc}d\end{align}
   \begin{align}(3+5)2/7&=\frac{6+10}7\\\\&\ne 6+\frac{10}7\end{align}
2. \begin{align}a+ b/c &= a+ \frac bc \\&\ne \frac{a+b}c\end{align}
   \begin{align}2+ 3/7 &= 2+ \frac 37 \\&\ne \frac{5}7\end{align}